# File Upload and TAKE PHOTO option using Input type=file in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6

I have a file input in my application (ionic 6 and vue 3) and when the it is triggered in iOS i get this three options.

[image: Input File options]

I found [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/want-to-disable-camera-features-in-ios-device-as-in-android-it-wont-display-the-camera-option-when-i-use-input-type-file-html-tag-it-is-an-ionic-app/228601) that some searching that these are OS defaults and cannot be changed.

**So now the question is there a way to identify if the user has chosen TAKE PHOTO option and trigger the camera action like stated [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/your-first-app/taking-photos) in Ionic docs.**

i.e if the PHOTO LIBRARY or FILES is chosen it follows the current path. But incase of TAKE PHOTO to have additional handling to handle the images.

How can i handle this ?

I am currently using the following code to handle the selection of file and upload of it when a button is clicked and a hidden input.

```
const selectFile = (event: any) => {
  attachmentFile.value = event.target.files[0];
  uploadAttachment();
};

const uploadAttachment = async () => {
  const file = attachmentFile.value;
  if (!file) return;
  const path = `${student_profile.value?.id}/${selectedType.value}-${file.name}`;
  const data = await uploadFileToStorage({ path: path, file: file });
  if (data) saveAttachmentMetaData(data.publicUrl);
};
```

HTML for buttons and file input

```
    <ion-item style="display: none">
      <input
        type="file"
        accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx,image/*"
        @change="selectFile($event)"
        ref="fileInput"
      />
    </ion-item>

    <ion-button
      @click="fileInput?.click()"
      :disabled="!selectedType"
      expand="block"
      >Select File</ion-button
    >
```